# Special characters pose problems with REST webservice communication

Tags: android, json, rest, special-characters

I am trying to post a JSON-object to a REST webservice from an Android application. Everything works fine until I add special characters like å, ä, ö.

```
JSONObject absenceObject = new JSONObject();
absenceObject.put(INFO_DESCRIPTION, "åka pendeltåg");
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(absenceObject.toString());
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json";character);
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

If I print `absenceObject.toString()` and copy the result in to a regular rest client it works fine as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try specifying the desired charset in the StringEntity constructor:

```
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(absenceObject.toString(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(body, "UTF-8");
            //wr.writeBytes(entity.toString());
            wr.writeUTF(entity.toString());  i had try both way but does't work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you control both ends of the pipe, you can encode the REST text as shown here [Encoding/decoding REST path parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485812/encoding-decoding-rest-path-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Re: Mark's response

> Try specifying the desired charset in the StringEntity constructor:
>
> StringEntity `entity = new StringEntity(absenceObject.toString(), "UTF-8");`

Note that setting charset after the constructor didn't work for me i.e.

```
entity.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
```

I had to do as Mark said and set it in the constructor.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] buf = body.getBytes(HTTP.UTF_8);
wr.write(buf, 0, buf.length);
```

Try this it will work.