# Sending special characters (ë ä ï) in POST body with DataOutputStream in Android

Tags: android, json, rest, post

Im currently working on an Android app with heavy server side communication. Yesterday I got a bug report saying that the users aren't able to send (simple) special characters such as ëäï.

I searched but didn't find anything helpful
Possible duplicate ( without answer ):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388974/android-httpurlconnection-post-special-charactes-to-rest-clint-in-android

My relevant code:

```
public void execute(String method) {
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(this.url);
            urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod(method);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(30 * 1000);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

            if (secure)
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + getCredentials());

            if (body != null) {
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");


                urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(body.length());
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeBytes(body);
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();
            }

            responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            message = urlConnection.getResponseMessage();

            InputStream in = null;

            try {
                in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream(), 2048);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getErrorStream(), 2048);
            }

            if (in != null)
                response = convertStreamToString(in);

        } catch (UnknownHostException no_con) {
            responseCode = 101;
        }catch (ConnectException no_con_2){
            responseCode = 101;
        }catch(IOException io_ex){
            if(io_ex.getMessage().contains("No authentication challenges found")){
                responseCode = 401;
            }else
                responseCode = 101;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null)
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

`body` is a String ;-)

Hope we can solve this together

UPDATE:

Tried:

---

```
writeUTF()
```

need a server capable of understanding the modified UTF-8

---

```
byte[] buf = body.getBytes("UTF-8");
dos.write(buf, 0, buf.length);
```

### strings work but no special chars

update: Got it working with StringEntity(* string, "UTF-8") then parse the result to a byte[] and write it with dos.write(byte[])!

--

Comment: read writeBytes documentation. use writeUTF instead.

Comment: sounds fair indeed. How do i get the length of that string. Im now getting an error on specifying the wrong length

Comment: that makes sense, since some characters are encoded on several bytes. you may try not to specify the length, you may use writeChars (but that's less efficient, as all chars would be 2-byte), you may use String.getBytes("UTF-8").length (but that creates a quite long useless byte[]). Also, please note that DataOutputStream.writeUTF is a custom format that adds the lenght of the string at the begining, and is intended to be read by a DataInputStream. (but that depends on your server)

Comment: Yeah, i got it working by not specifying a length. But the server is not in Java and does not recognize the writeUTF modified UTF encoding. Any other thoughts ?

Comment: Also tried byte[] buf = body.getBytes("UTF-8"); dos.write(buf, 0, buf.length); But the special chars are still not working

Comment: if the server does not recognize the writeUTF, don't use a DataOutputStream, directly use the outputStream. write(buf, 0, buf.length) should work, but then it may be on your server side.

Comment: there is another clue pointing to a server side issue : the header charset=UTF-8 should have caused a crash when you used writeBytes(String), as this generate a byte[] that is not compatible with UTF-8 decoding. Your server probably doesn't try to read utf-8

Comment: @Mark'pxr'Mooibroek : convert the special characters to corresponding ascii value and send... in the server side, convert back to special character..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the encoding of the StringEntity did the trick for me:

```
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(body, "UTF-8");
```

seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5819465/570168

Comment: StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(body, "UTF-8");
1) wr.writeBytes(entity.toString());
2) wr.writeUTF(entity.toString()); i had try both way but does't work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i am not totally sure buy try this utility for your case 
URLEncoder.encode(string, "UTF-8")

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem in android while passing a json with special char (ñ).
In my WebApi method, [FromBody] param is giving null, it seems it can't parse the json.

I got it working by getting bytes as UTF-8 then writing it in DataOutputStream (Client-side fix).

```
byte[] b = jsonString.getBytes("UTF-8");
os.write(b, 0, b.length);
```