# c# httpclient POST request: cant send special characters

Tags: c#, encoding, httpclient, urlencode

I have a program that should login to site, it uses POST requests, and all goes fine, until one of the values contain special character('%' for example).

```
    captcha = "ABCDE" //all goes fine and well, server accept captcha
    captcha = "ABC&%" //server dont accept captcha and return fail

    //here is the bad part:
    string request = "password=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(encpass, Encoding.UTF8) +
 "&username=" + login + "&captcha_text=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(captcha, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Also, i ofcourse googled it, and checked all i could find. I though i need to "warn" server abaut encoding, so i added

```
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
```

but it still did not helped me.

Content types and way request should look like i get from Firebug, so if i can find some answers there - please point.

**modify0:** Also, i compared what my program send to server with browser request(using Firebug) and my request is completley same. Only difference - my request dont get accepted in values it contain special-characters.

**modify1:** Also, server have no problems handling special-characters when i check it in browser. For example it(browser) sent "K&YF82" as "captcha_text=K%26YF82"(same value in addres propereties and request body) and all worked fine. UrlEncode do same replacement, but in my program it doesnt get accepted by server.

**SOLUTION:**

```
{ password:"df464dsj", username:"username", captchaText:"ABC&%", remember_login:"false" }
```

insteat of

```
password=f2341f14f&username=username&captha...
```

Comment: server dont recognize captcha and return fail? what are you receiving on server? have you debugged it?

Comment: Are you decoding the value appropriately on the server?  What error are you actually getting?

Comment: {"success":false,"message":"Error verifying humanity","captcha_needed":true}  Thats what i get when captcha contains special-character. And when its not - captcha is accepted and no error.

Comment: {"success":false,"captcha_needed":true,"message":"Incorrect login"} And here answer for captcha with only letters and numbers. Its still fail becouse password contains special characters too. Thats why i think that problem in spec-chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you dealing with REST application??

If yes then send your post data in request body instead of query string.

Also have a look at the stack post at : [Special characters pose problems with REST webservice communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819431/special-characters-pose-problems-with-rest-webservice-communication/5819465#5819465)

Comment: I found this link before and tryed to form string with it: StringContent request = new StringContent(requestData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); didnt help.
Also i checked request body and query string, they both have same parameters in different order, so i did it this way in my code too.
Problem in symbols, not in parameters location i think. Server accept captcha as long as it didnt contain special-characters. So, its root of all evils.

Comment: This link can help you http://serverfault.com/questions/257680/properly-handle-iis-request-with-percent-sign-in-url

OR 

write your own template to handle such special characters and replace while doing HTTP POST and server will terat them as special charcater,

Comment: It makes me feel like i post too few information, but if i post all i found and checked - it`ll take like 5 pages and noone will read it. Server not blocking %, it works great in captcha in browser. Problems start in my program. (gonna update main post in minute)

Comment: Can you post your actual query string or request body which you see in fiddler?
Do you see content like below?
password=somepassword&usename=someuser&captcha_text=ABCD

Comment: Captcha "Y@&NQL", query string sent by browser "password=fvQnb%2B6<**pass cut**>C1gxtqNQ%3D%3D&username=mylogin&captcha_text=Y%40%26NQL&remember_login=false"
captcha encoded same in body and in query string.

Comment: Not once i carefully compared what my program generates and what was sent by browser - it works in same logic. same replacements made. Only difference that when browser sent things like "Y%40%26NQL" as captcha - all went fine, and when program do - capthcha not accepted. So, somehow server recognize numbers and digits and have problems with special characters sent by my program.

Comment: Hm.. last try... can you revert back to response body and use JSON as your content type with the below structure? { password:"df464dsj", username:"username", captchaText:"ABC&%", remember_login:"false" }.

Comment: its working. THANK YOU!
it still didnt accept encrypted password(wich contains "/+="), probably something is wrong with quotes or something, but i finally get out from dead end. This way all kind of captchas accepted by server, so encoding is fine. Thank you again.

Comment: I donno. There is another post request before this with login name, probably i should do it this way too and all gonna be fine. Or maybe some fail with qoutes. But captcha was accepted both ways **<,\"captcha_text\":\"" + captcha + "\",>** and **<,captcha_text:\"" + captcha + "\",>** . Both was fine for server. So, probably some other mistake. I`ll find it out after some sleep. Woke up yesterday, as i recall :)

Comment: btw, interesting, why both fiddler and firebug gave me this "pass=safsd&user=user" instead of proper JSON? Or maybe i was watching wrong field?

Comment: The way content is formatted in that form it will appear. If you quote them as string it will appear as quoted string else not, I use chrome more to check the content in console, don't remember how it appears in FF.